# Azure notification hub metric displaying lot of incoming messages

Tags: azure, azure-notificationhub

I am using Azure Notification Hub for sending push notifications. When I looked into Metric from Azure portal, I do see a lot of incoming messages ex: more than 4K and successful notification is 211 only.

[image: Azure Notification Hubs - Metric]

Is this an expected behaviour? And I don't see any APNS / GCM errors.

Comment: Were you able to ever get an answer to this?

Comment: @Micah No :( Only one answer, that got deleted :(

Comment: I am seeing if anyone internally at Microsoft can answer this for you. Unfortunately it a bit out of my expertise but hopefully someone will get back to me shortly with at least some direction for you.

Comment: So one thing I heard back was that it appears that the total number of incoming messages is likely not only from notifications which is why you see a difference. Not sure what they are from though. I was pointed to this documentation to review what counts as incoming for the metrics counters. I am still reviewing it but thought I would share regardless. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-overview-metrics

Comment: @Anuraj I have same problem. Did u find out what is the problem ?

Comment: Can you both select your Metrics Chart -> Edit Chart and chose chart type:

APNS Authorization 
APNS Bad Channel Error
APNS Errors
APNS Expired Channel Error

Maybe we can see what happened to the other incoming messages. 

Also, here is a link on the descriptions for each metric: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-supported-metrics

Comment: @Micah There are no any errors. To understand. I had a moment when it was like 150 incoming messages and 2 outgoing (1 to IOS and 1 to android). I had this problem from 11 am to 14 pm. Then it started work again. I afraid that it happens again

Comment: @SashaFentsyk Nope. I am still facing the issue. And I couldn't find docs which talks about this :(